# PC reboots 10-20 minutes after shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, shutdown

I run a dual boot pc with Windows and Ubuntu, with Windows being the main OS on the BIOS. They are also on 2 separate solid state drives.

When I shutdown the pc when I'm in Windows, the computer shuts down normally. When I shutdown the pc when I'm in Ubuntu, it shuts down but the computer will reboot 10-20 minutes later, eventually booting back into Windows as it's my main OS on the BIOS.

Why isn't the Ubuntu OS doing a complete shutdown?

Comment: Some specifics may help, what release are you talking about?  a desktop? server? or other system?  if using a LTS release which stack are you using? (GA or HWE) and how heavily have you modified it? (esp. 3rd party packages). What command are you using to shutdown? and have you tried other commands?

Comment: In a terminal window, the command `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs. Check for "timeout" messages.